# Buscador de tiendas API de Google

Tags: php, javascript, json, google-maps

Buenas es la primera vez que estoy utilizando la API de google para hacer un buscador de los centros más cercanos. Pero no consigo que me cargue la página de ningún modo.

**Archivo `phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php`**

```
<?php
$username="username";
$password="password";
$database="databaseName";
?>
```

**Archivo mapas php EL PHP**

```
require("phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php");
// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];
// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect (82.223.13.57, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}
// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}
// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, name, address, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}
header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("id", $row['id']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

**Archivo mapas php EL HTML**

```
<div class="col-12" style="height:300px;" style="padding:0px;">
  <div style="margin-top:5%; margin-bottom: 5%;">
    <label for="raddressInput">Search location:</label>
      <input type="text" id="addressInput" size="15"/>
      <label for="radiusSelect">Radius:</label>
      <select id="radiusSelect" label="Radius">
        <option value="50" selected>50 kms</option>
        <option value="30">30 kms</option>
        <option value="20">20 kms</option>
        <option value="10">10 kms</option>
      </select>
        input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search"/>
     </div>
     <div><select id="locationSelect" style="width:100%;visibility:hidden"></select></div>
     <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 80%"></div>
 </div>
```

**Archivo mapas php EL JAVASCRIPT**

```
 var map;
      var markers = [];
      var infoWindow;
      var locationSelect;

        function initMap() {
          var sydney = {lat: -33.863276, lng: 151.107977};
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: sydney,
            zoom: 11,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
          });
          infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

          searchButton = document.getElementById("searchButton").onclick = searchLocations;

          locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
          locationSelect.onchange = function() {
            var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
            if (markerNum != "none"){
              google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
            }
          };
        }

       function searchLocations() {
         var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
         var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
           } else {
             alert(address + ' not found');
           }
         });
       }

       function clearLocations() {
         infoWindow.close();
         for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
           markers[i].setMap(null);
         }
         markers.length = 0;

         locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
         var option = document.createElement("option");
         option.value = "none";
         option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
         locationSelect.appendChild(option);
       }

       function searchLocationsNear(center) {
         clearLocations();

         var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
         var searchUrl = 'storelocator.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
         downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
           var xml = parseXml(data);
           var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
           var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
           for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
             var id = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("id");
             var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
             var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
             var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
             var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                  parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

             createOption(name, distance, i);
             createMarker(latlng, name, address);
             bounds.extend(latlng);
           }
           map.fitBounds(bounds);
           locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
           locationSelect.onchange = function() {
             var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
             google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
           };
         });
       }

       function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }

       function createOption(name, distance, num) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = num;
          option.innerHTML = name;
          locationSelect.appendChild(option);
       }

       function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
          var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
              new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
              new XMLHttpRequest;

          request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
              request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
              callback(request.responseText, request.status);
            }
          };

          request.open('GET', url, true);
          request.send(null);
       }

       function parseXml(str) {
          if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
            doc.loadXML(str);
            return doc;
          } else if (window.DOMParser) {
            return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
          }
       }

       function doNothing() {}
```

Comment: No estás usando Google Apps Script.

Comment: Hola @Ruben, perdona e estado fuera y no vi el mensaje, desde Google Apps Script se puede hacer, es que no lo encuentro

Comment: Quizás esto es lo que requires -> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/

Comment: Hola @Rubén no entiendo mucho lo que me pasas, la verdad que esto de el buscador de centros es mi nemesis desde hace unos años. Simplemente lo que quiero hacer es que pongan el código postal y les salga en el mapa el centro más cercano, alguna sugerencia???

Comment: ¿Las direcciones de los centros son conocidas?

Comment: No, tienen que ser sacada de un BD que esta ya creada una de prueba @Rubén

Comment: Si las direcciones están en una BD entonces, para efectos de mi pregunta, son conocidas. Con un SQL deberías poder encontrar el centro con base en el C.P. y así sólo Google Maps API para mostrar la ubicación e incluso podrías usar Google Apps Script para ello.

Comment: Si exacto, pero tiene que ser con un rango de 5km (por ejemplo) o que siempre muestre el más cercano, por si no hay uno en ese C.P

Comment: Te sugiero editar la pregunta para agregar los detalles que mencionas y si te interesa como alternativa a PHP / Google Maps API el uso de Google Apps Script, publica una nueva pregunta, claro luego de haber buscado/investigado sobre este.

Comment: Ya he investigado mucho, pero sigo conseguir nada de nada, ahora lo tengo algo mejor, pero siempre me muestra el mar, utilizando la API de google

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89329/discussion-between-ruben-and-miguel).